# Timestamp in Rust's Diesel Library with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I have been taking a look at Rust's [Diesel ORM](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel) today by following along on [this walk-through](http://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started/), and I can't get a `Timestamp` to work.

**Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "0.6.2", features = ["chrono"] }
diesel_codegen = { version = "0.6.2", default-features = false, features = ["nightly", "postgres"] }
dotenv = "0.8.0"
dotenv_macros = "0.8.0"
```

**models.rs**

```
#[derive(Queryable)]

pub struct Author {
    pub id: i32,
    pub first_name: String,
    pub last_name: String,
    pub email: String
}

pub struct Post {
    pub id: i32,
    pub author: Author,
    pub title: String,
    pub body: String,
    pub published: bool,
    pub created: Timestamp,
    pub updated: Timestamp
}
```

(I read that there's a `diesel::types::Timestamp` type)

**lib.rs**

```
#![feature(custom_derive, custom_attribute, plugin)]
#![plugin(diesel_codegen, dotenv_macros)]

#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;
extern crate dotenv;

pub mod schema;
pub mod models;

use diesel::prelude::*;
use diesel::types::Timestamp;
use diesel::pg::PgConnection;
use dotenv::dotenv;
use std::env;

pub fn establish_connection() -> PgConnection {
    dotenv().ok();

    let database_url = env::var("DATABASE_URL").
        expect("DATABASE_URL must be set");
    PgConnection::establish(&database_url).
        expect(&format!("Error connecting to {}", database_url))
}
```

But these are the errors I get when I try to use it:

```
<diesel macros>:5:1: 5:71 note: in this expansion of table_body! (defined in <diesel macros>)
src/schema.rs:1:1: 1:40 note: in this expansion of table! (defined in <diesel macros>)
src/schema.rs:1:1: 1:40 note: in this expansion of infer_schema! (defined in src/lib.rs)
src/lib.rs:1:1: 1:1 help: run `rustc --explain E0412` to see a detailed explanation
src/lib.rs:1:1: 1:1 help: no candidates by the name of `Timestamptz` found in your project; maybe you misspelled the name or forgot to import an external crate?
src/lib.rs:1:1: 1:1 error: type name `Timestamptz` is undefined or not in scope [E0412]
src/lib.rs:1 #![feature(custom_derive, custom_attribute, plugin)]

...

<diesel macros>:38:1: 38:47 note: in this expansion of column! (defined in <diesel macros>)
<diesel macros>:5:1: 5:71 note: in this expansion of table_body! (defined in <diesel macros>)
src/schema.rs:1:1: 1:40 note: in this expansion of table! (defined in <diesel macros>)
src/schema.rs:1:1: 1:40 note: in this expansion of infer_schema! (defined in src/lib.rs)
src/lib.rs:1:1: 1:1 help: run `rustc --explain E0412` to see a detailed explanation
src/lib.rs:1:1: 1:1 help: no candidates by the name of `Timestamptz` found in your project; maybe you misspelled the name or forgot to import an external crate?
src/models.rs:16:18: 16:27 error: type name `Timestamp` is undefined or not in scope [E0412]
src/models.rs:16     pub created: Timestamp,
                              ^~~~~~~~~
src/models.rs:16:18: 16:27 help: run `rustc --explain E0412` to see a detailed explanation
src/models.rs:16:18: 16:27 help: you can import it into scope: `use diesel::types::Timestamp;`.
src/models.rs:17:18: 17:27 error: type name `Timestamp` is undefined or not in scope [E0412]
src/models.rs:17     pub updated: Timestamp
                              ^~~~~~~~~
```

It looks like the first error, `Timestamptz` is a result of `infer_schema` not knowing how to interpret that Postgresql type, which is already in the table. As for the second, I thought perhaps if explicitly imported that `Timestamp` type, I could create a `Post` struct with it.

Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong here?

As an aside, I am pretty new to Rust and Diesel uses a fair bit of code-generation, so it's easy to get lost, but I thought this should be a straightforward thing to accomplish.

---

**Edit**:

I used `timestamp with time zone` to create the table, and it looks like that [may not be supported yet](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/106):

```
CREATE TABLE post (
    ...
    created timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    updated timestamp with time zone
)
```

---

**Edit 2:**

I changed **models.rs** to look like the following and got rid of the error about `Timestamp` being undefined. I also realized that I needed `#[derive(Queryable)]` above each of the structs to be derived. The following compiles fine, but the previous errors with `Timestamptz` remain:

```
use diesel::types::Timestamp;

#[derive(Queryable)]
pub struct Author {
    pub id: i32,
    pub first_name: String,
    pub last_name: String,
    pub email: String
}

#[derive(Queryable)]
pub struct Post {
    pub id: i32,
    pub author: Author,
    pub title: String,
    pub body: String,
    pub published: bool,
    pub created: Timestamp,
    pub updated: Timestamp
}
```

Comment: Looks like it may not be supported yet, so I may have to go with a naive datetime for now: https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/106

Comment: You know my favorite part about ORMs is the input sanitization so I don't have to think as much about SQL injection. I've heard them called leaky abstractions and it's probably true because you have to know a lot of SQL to use most ORMs effectively. Of course, you also have to write a ton of boilerplate marshalling types into and out of SQL types. Have you used SQLalchemy? It gets best-in-show in my limited experience.

Comment: ORMs get in the way, write slow queries, and hide problems from the programmer. You can end up doing seriously stupid things, but unless you read the SQL statements the stupid ORM is writing, you'd never know until you wonder why the thing is dog slow and realize you've ended up doing sequential scans with joins for absolutely no good reason.

Comment: I don't share that opinion. I think they serve a role. I won't try to change your time about them, though.

Comment: The issue was fixed by the Diesel team.

I share the same views and concerns of @ZanLynx with respecto to ORMs, however, the advantage of being able to move between database engines, is a plus, consider change to be a constant in Software, what happens when people need to move from MySQL to a Serverless Database? The price of Freedom is eternal vigilance, so we must observe the ORM's behaviour closely, and not let the abstraction bite is us the behind.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

All of the types in [`diesel::sql_types`](http://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/sql_types/index.html) are markers to represent various SQL datatypes for your schema. They should never be used in your own structs. What you need is a type which implements `diesel::deserialize::FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Timestamp, diesel::pg::Pg>` (docs: [`FromSql`](http://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/deserialize/trait.FromSql.html), [`Timestamp`](http://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/sql_types/struct.Timestamp.html), [`Pg`](http://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/pg/struct.Pg.html)). There are two types which implement that trait.

The first is [`std::time::SystemTime`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/time/struct.SystemTime.html) which doesn't require additional dependencies, but doesn't have a ton of capabilities.

The second is [`chrono::NaiveDateTime`](https://lifthrasiir.github.io/rust-chrono/chrono/naive/datetime/struct.NaiveDateTime.html). This is probably the type you want. In order to use it, you'll need to add [`chrono`](https://crates.io/crates/chrono) to your dependencies, and change the diesel line in Cargo.toml to include the chrono feature, so it'll look something like `diesel = { version = "0.7.0", features = ["postgres", "chrono"] }`

(Technically there's a third type, which is [`diesel::data_types::PgTimestamp`](http://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/pg/data_types/struct.PgTimestamp.html) but that's almost certainly not what you want, as that struct is just the literal representation of timestamp in the database so other types don't have to worry about raw bytes)

Comment: There is a great compilation of Diesel, PostgreSQL and Rust's data type mappings [here](https://kotiri.com/2018/01/31/postgresql-diesel-rust-types.html)

Comment: Best answer! Thank you for your wisdom!

Answer (score 0):

please check datatype from ui

"src/models.rs:16:18: 16:27 help: you can import it into scope: `use diesel::types::Timestamp;`.
src/models.rs:17:18: 17:27 error: type name `Timestamp` is undefined or not in scope [E0412]
src/models.rs:17     pub updated: Timestamp "

maybe timestamp is not define word.

Comment: One thing you were right about: I accidentally imported that type in the wrong file!